# Maintaining data in variable in loop

Tags: c#

The problem I am having with my code is that it opens one of the files in the folder and reads the first line, if it is the header (HDR) then it assigns that line to the currentHDR variable, it will then search for an ERROR on the file, and it ommits two common errors that are known, if there is an error, it should then write the line currentHDR and the line into the report file, it will then assign the currnetHDR to the current variable. This is to ensure that when it checks next on that same file, that any further errors are written without writing the header line. When it is finished and opens the new file, there should be something still assigned to "current" and that is why it checks if current is not null and if so, it makes current null. and continues with the loop.

This is the code:

```
private string folderPath;
private object file;
public string current { get; private set; }
public string currentHDR { get; private set; }

public void Main()
{
  folderPath = "C:\\data\\";

  foreach (string pathToFile in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.BER"))
  {
    using (System.IO.StreamWriter file =
         new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\data\newreport.txt", true))
    {
      foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(pathToFile))
      {
        if (line.Contains("HDR") && current == null)
        {
          string currentHDR = line;
        }
        else if (line.Contains("HDR") && current != null)
        {
          string currentHDR = line;
          current = "";
        }

        if (line.Contains("ERR~") && line.Contains("Warnings exist"))
        { }
        else
        {
          if (line.Contains("ERR~") && line.Contains("DEPARTPORT"))
          { }
          else
          {
            if (line.Contains("ERR~WARNING") && current == null)
            {
              file.WriteLine(currentHDR);
              file.WriteLine(line);
              current = currentHDR;
            }
            else if (line.Contains("ERR~WARNING") && current != null)
            {
              file.WriteLine(line);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

The result file at the moment looks like this:

> ERR~WARNING - SHP.TPTCTRY () cannot be empty for SHP.TPTID (xxx);
>
> ERR~WARNING - SHP.TPTCTRY () cannot be empty for SHP.TPTID (xxx);

which clearly shows that currentHDR is empty at the point it tries to write that line out to the file. for what I can see, as it goes through the loop it seems to not continue to hold the value in the variable.

Am I misunderstanding how this is failing?

Comment: Can you take a moment and fix the code formatting?

Comment: @Amy better now?

Comment: whats the desired behavior? please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Side note: file shouldn't be declared "object".  It's a StreamWriter.

Comment: Leave the question as a question, no need to put the "results" from the answer in it.

Comment: @LarsTech thanks! That was intelisense suggestion before I had done something else and I left it there by accident

Comment: @LarsTech LuckyLikey was asking for the desired behavior/outcome, just showing what the file would look like...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with these lines:

```
if (line.Contains("HDR") && current == null)
{
   string currentHDR = line;
}
else if (line.Contains("HDR") && current != null)
{
   string currentHDR = line;
   current = "";
}
```

Note that you are using `string currentHDR = ...`, which means you are declaring a different `currentHDR` variable scoped to each `if` block. Remove the `string` type declaration and you will, then, be using the `currentHDR` field that you expected:

```
if (line.Contains("HDR") && current == null)
{
   currentHDR = line;
}
else if (line.Contains("HDR") && current != null)
{
   currentHDR = line;
   current = "";
}
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Explanation makes sense and resolved my problem.....thank you!